# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC, I have a CustomTableViewController and I'm adding a CustomView to my background cell, header and footer.

For example in the `tableView:viewForFooterInSection` method i put these lines of code:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CustomFooter *footer = [[CustomFooter alloc] init];
    return footer;
}
```

CustomFooter is a subclass of UIView that draws a rectangle as background cell with `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`

When i runs the application on the simulator works but it crash when i try on my iPhone.

How can i fix it?

This is my crash report:

```
Date/Time:       2012-06-28 12:37:07.168 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000009
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3508cf78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x372d5e90 CFRetain + 76
2   CoreFoundation                  0x372dfb74 +[__NSArrayI __new::] + 48
3   CoreFoundation                  0x372dfa8e -[__NSPlaceholderArray   initWithObjects:count:] + 294
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3730ce68 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:] + 460
5   CustomTable                     0x0004766e drawLinearGradient (Common.m:15)
6   CustomTable                     0x00048c14 -[CustomFooter drawRect:]   (CustomFooter.m:50)
7   UIKit                           0x3107015e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 270
8   QuartzCore                      0x374b74de -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 110
9   QuartzCore                      0x374b6b38 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1776
10  QuartzCore                      0x374b632e CA::Layer::display_() + 950
11  QuartzCore                      0x374b5f5a CA::Layer::display() + 122
12  QuartzCore                      0x374b5e9c CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 168
13  QuartzCore                      0x374b5844 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 228
14  QuartzCore                      0x374b5578 CA::Transaction::commit() + 308
15  QuartzCore                      0x374dd90a CA::Transaction::flush() + 38
16  QuartzCore                      0x374dd8dc +[CATransaction flush] + 28
17  UIKit                           0x310a6108 -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 36
18  UIKit                           0x31093b2c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 1256
19  UIKit                           0x31061abc -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1004
20  UIKit                           0x31061560 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
21  UIKit                           0x31060f34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
22  GraphicsServices                0x33aa3224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3736151c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
24  CoreFoundation                  0x373614be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3736030c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
26  CoreFoundation                  0x372e349e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
27  CoreFoundation                  0x372e3366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
28  UIKit                           0x31092864 -[UIApplication _run] + 544
29  UIKit                           0x3108fcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
30  CustomTable                     0x00046798 main (main.m:16)
31  CustomTable                     0x0004673c start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315343a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x304b9ea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x304b9bc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31544cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bfcf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bfccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31544cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bfcf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bfccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31534004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315341fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x373613ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37360124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x372e349e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x372e3366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x32c8cc9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33c0272e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33c025e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x00125860    r1: 0x30d16b7c      r2: 0x3f9a3570      r3: 0x0014b170
r4: 0x00000001    r5: 0x2fe41188      r6: 0x0014b178      r7: 0x2fe4114c
r8: 0x0014b170    r9: 0x0c345adf     r10: 0x00000002     r11: 0x00000001
ip: 0x3f97f814    sp: 0x2fe41140      lr: 0x372d5e97      pc: 0x3508cf78
cpsr: 0x00000030
```

This is my drawRect function into CustomFooter:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGColorRef whiteColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor; 
CGColorRef lightGrayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
CGColorRef darkGrayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:187.0/255.0 green:187.0/255.0 blue:187.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
CGColorRef shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:0.5].CGColor;

CGFloat paperMargin = 9.0;
CGRect paperRect = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x+paperMargin, 
                              self.bounds.origin.y,
                              self.bounds.size.width-paperMargin*2, 
                              self.bounds.size.height);

CGRect arcRect = paperRect;
arcRect.size.height = 8;

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGMutablePathRef arcPath = createArcPathFromBottomOfRect(arcRect, 4.0);
CGContextAddPath(context, arcPath);
CGContextClip(context);            
drawLinearGradient(context, paperRect, lightGrayColor, darkGrayColor);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGPoint pointA = CGPointMake(arcRect.origin.x, 
                             arcRect.origin.y + arcRect.size.height - 1);
CGPoint pointB = CGPointMake(arcRect.origin.x, arcRect.origin.y);
CGPoint pointC = CGPointMake(arcRect.origin.x + arcRect.size.width - 1, 
                             arcRect.origin.y);
CGPoint pointD = CGPointMake(arcRect.origin.x + arcRect.size.width - 1, 
                             arcRect.origin.y + arcRect.size.height - 1);
draw1PxStroke(context, pointA, pointB, whiteColor);
draw1PxStroke(context, pointC, pointD, whiteColor);    
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGContextAddRect(context, paperRect);
CGContextAddPath(context, arcPath);
CGContextEOClip(context);
CGContextAddPath(context, arcPath);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 2), 3.0, shadowColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CFRelease(arcPath);
}
```

drawLinearGradient

```
void drawLinearGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef  endColor)
{
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColor, (__bridge id)endColor, nil];
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

}
```

Comment: Show us the crash log / stack trace.

Comment: The problem appears to be in your `drawRect` method.  Please post the code for that method.

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be in `drawLinearRect()`.  Can we see the code for that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JeremyP's analysis of the array initializer crash is correct. I'm guessing the root cause is:

`CGColorRef whiteColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;`

My guess is that since you don't use the `UIColor` you create beyond this statement, it will be eagerly released by ARC. That also means that the `CGColor` that you didn't retain in any way (and which ARC won't retain for you) is probably also released and dealloced.

Try working it around with something like this for each of the UIColors (and for the white one, just use `[UIColor whiteColor]`):

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor ...];
CGColorRef cgColor = CFRetain(color.CGColor);
color = nil;
```

Comment: Solved! It was exactly the passing of the colors to the method drawLineGradient. I solved it by passing a UIColor the method and converted to CGColor.
`NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];`

Comment: an even easier fix is to store and pass around the UIColor, and then use myColor.CGColor when needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough context here to diagnose the issue with any certainty, but my current guess is that your function `drawLinearRect()` creates an `NSArray` using `arrayWithObjects:` and one of the objects in the parameter list is garbage.  Make sure that the list is nil terminated and all the objects in it are sensible.

Comment: Yes, you're right! the problem is in the array that contains the colors of the gradient. But How can this happen? I post `drawLineGradient`